# Python re regex sub letters not surrounded in quotes and not if they match specific word including regex group / match

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I need to sub letters not surrounded in quotes and not if they match the word `TODAY` with a particular string where a part of it includes the match group e.g.

```py
import re
import string

s = 'AB+B+" HELLO"+TODAY()/C* 100'
x = re.sub(r'\"[^"]*\"|\bTODAY\b|([A-Z]+)', r'a2num("\g<0>")', s)

print (x)
```

expected output:

```py
'a2num("AB")+a2num("B")+" HELLO"+TODAY()/a2num("C")* 100'
```

actual output:

```py
'a2num("AB")+a2num("B")+a2num("" HELLO"")+a2num("TODAY")()/a2num("C")* 100'
```

I am nearly there but it is not obeying the quote rules or the `TODAY` word rule, I know the string doesn't make any sense but it's just a harsh test of the regex

Comment: You only need to match capital letters?

Comment: @00 Yes, the whole string will have been upper cased before hand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex approach is correct but you need to use a lambda function in `re.sub`

```
>>> s = 'AB+B+" HELLO"+TODAY()/C* 100'
>>> rs = re.sub(r'"[^"]*"|\bTODAY\b|\b([A-Z]+)\b',
...     lambda m: 'a2num("' + m.group(1) + '")' if m.group(1) else m.group(), s)
>>> print (rs)

a2num("AB")+a2num("B")+" HELLO"+TODAY()/a2num("C")* 100
```

[**Code Demo**](https://ideone.com/rODafc)